# jQuery button append space issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am appending buttons using jQuery append method.

```
$('#btnContainer').on('click', '.btn', function(){

    var test  = $('<input>', {
                    type: 'button',  // Set type of input element                  
                    class: 'btn', // Applies class btn
                    value: 'Button', //sets value of Button
                    click: function () { }
                });

    $("#btnContainer").append(test);    

});
```

Not able to understand the 1st button right space is more then others after appending.
I am not applying any other css also. (See image for more info)
[image]

CODE:
http://jsfiddle.net/ajaypatel_aj/XCsNu/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type="text/css">
.btn{
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.2;![enter image description here][2]
    white-space:nowrap;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="btnContainer">
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="Button" />
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="application/javascript">

$('#btnContainer').on('click', '.btn', function(){

    var test  = $('<input/>', {
                    type: 'button',  // Set type of input element                  
                    class: 'btn', // Applies class btn
                    value: 'Button', //sets value of Button
                    click: function () { }
                });

    $("#btnContainer").append(test);    

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Try the updated code and see the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify this html

```
<div id="btnContainer">
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="Button" />
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="btnContainer"><input type="button" class="btn" value="Button" /></div>
```

The whitespace inside the div is causing this issue.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XCsNu/2/

Answer (score 2):

This is to do with the whitespace which is around the original button. Appended elements are placed directly at the end of any existing content, so do not have this problem. Therefore you can force the white-space to collapse by setting `float: left;` on the `.btn` elements.

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XCsNu/1/)